# Working example on Scheduling in WSO2 DSS

Tags: database, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I am working on WSO2 DSS 3.0.1 with Postgresql as DataBase.
Can any one give me working  example on  **Scheduling in WSO2 DSS** 
How to schedule the data service 
How it is working and benefits of this scheduling these services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [document](http://docs.wso2.org/display/DSS310/Scheduling+Tasks) will give you an idea about how scheduling in WSO2_DSS

UPDATE 1:
The following [blog](http://itsmeisuru.wordpress.com/2013/11/29/wso2-dss-scheduled-task-example/) post shows a step by step, working example on this. I think it will help you to solve your issue. There I used cassandra db to explain the scenario.

UPDATE 2:

create Scheduled task in DSS,
Go to,
`Home > Manage > Services > Add > Data Service > Scheduled Tasks > Add New Task`
in DSS Server and in
 `Data Service Specific Information > Scheduling Type`
drop down select
 `DataService Task Class`

In `DataService Task Class` field you must specify the fully qualified class name. (eg: `com.example.DssSchedlueTask.ScheduledDataTask_abcCompany`)

This is the 6th step of the above mentioned blog post example.

Hope this help you to solve your issue...

Comment: HI Isuru again thank you,i written emp dataservice for select and insert operations, i scheduled the emp service, in scheduled task.And i did n't change any configuration . While i am inserting or selecting data from TRYIt side, scheduling is not working...please guide me how to schedule this emp service..

Comment: Are you using the RDBMSSample for this?

Comment: Yes Isuru,here is sample emp data service **https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7702508 **

Comment: @Kanchetianeel I updated the answer with more info. Hope it will answer your questions.

Comment: Hi Isuru ,Thank you,i tried  as u said but instead of Cassandra i used the Postgresql,After i copy the jar file wso2 DSS in lib floder and restart the server ,there no scheduled on Wso2 DSS termina side.Here i am sending my Git Url. Please check me once..**https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7747764**

Comment: @Kanchetianeel Did you follow the instructions in step 6 of this post, http://itsmeisuru.wordpress.com/2013/11/29/wso2-dss-scheduled-task-example/
Scheduled task won't run until you complete this step and click the schedule button.
have a look there's a screen shot is attached.

Comment: @Kanchetianeel what happened to your issue?
Could you solve it or need more help on this?

Comment: @Kanchetianeel answer updated. If you find this helpful, be generous to accept or up vote the answer.

Comment: Hi Isuru Thank you,  From first onwards i follow these steps **UPDATE 2** , but there is no scheduling on Wso2 DSS terminal side..Could you please help me

Comment: Even there no  failure or success message,when i am creating the scheduling task , on terminal it's showing _ **[2013-12-03 11:33:58,021]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ntask.core.impl.AbstractQuartzTaskManager} -  Task scheduled: [-1234][DATA_SERVICE_TASK][abcCompanyUpdateSales]
* _ ,after that i click this schedule button on UI side or i am inserting data into data base,there is no message on terminal side..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42391/discussion-between-itsmeisuru-and-kanchetianeel)